std::println/print not working in Winlibs MinGW (gcc 14.1)
I was testing out the new <print> library in GCC 14.1 and tried to compile a program with std::println() only to be greeted with this (I've removed my name from the Users directory for privacy):
C:/Users/name/Documents/Compilers/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFbwKqp.o:testing.cpp:(.text$_ZSt14vprint_unicodeP6_iobufSt17basic_string_viewIcSt11char_traitsIcEESt17basic_format_argsISt20basic_format_contextINSt8__format10_Sink_iterIcEEcEE[_ZSt14vprint_unicodeP6_iobufSt17basic_string_viewIcSt11char_traitsIcEESt17basic_format_argsISt20basic_format_contextINSt8__format10_Sink_iterIcEEcEE]+0x107): undefined reference to `std::__open_terminal(_iobuf*)'
C:/Users/name/Documents/Compilers/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFbwKqp.o:testing.cpp:(.text$_ZSt14vprint_unicodeP6_iobufSt17basic_string_viewIcSt11char_traitsIcEESt17basic_format_argsISt20basic_format_contextINSt8__format10_Sink_iterIcEEcEE[_ZSt14vprint_unicodeP6_iobufSt17basic_string_viewIcSt11char_traitsIcEESt17basic_format_argsISt20basic_format_contextINSt8__format10_Sink_iterIcEEcEE]+0x240): undefined reference to `std::__write_to_terminal(void*, std::span<char, 18446744073709551615ull>)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I got the compiler from this website (specifically this one) and have never had any problems with their compilers before. I've tried compiling this code on Compiler Explorer and it worked fine. Can anyone tell me why this is happening on my machine?
minimal reproducible example(g++ -std=c++2c -o testing testing.cpp):
#include <print>
int main()
{
    std::println("hello world");
}


either your compiler is broken or you're not using it correctly, difficult to tell without a [mre]

How are you invoking the compiler? Your code as it is won't compile due to missing headers

Works for me on Linux. Likely a broken compiler.

sorry Alan Birtles, forgot to add the includes and compiler args. This code is what I'm running and i've added the compiler arguments as well

My guess would be it's linking to the wrong standard library, i think gcc can show which libraries it's linking to, you should check whether these symbols are actually in those libraries

Cannot reproduce with a standard install of gcc via msys2. Add -v to your command line and check that all your includes and libraries are coming from gcc 14.1.

You can know about std::print and std::println (on Windows you need to use the -lstdc++exp link)  from the gcc 14.1 changes notice.

I tried using that flag (along with the ones I was using before) and get the same result

@SHIPWECK Works on my end (but with MSYS2 GCC). Are you sure you're adding this flag to the right of testing.cpp? -l have no effect when specified to the left of source/object files.

Interestingly, Clang seems to pass -lstdc++exp automatically.

@HolyBlackCat where are you adding this? Particularly interested in how to do this with a cmake build

@J.N. The flag? I tested by building directly in the terminal. In CMake you probably want target_link_libraries.

@HolyBlackCat, thats what i tried. Unfortunately that did not fix the situation.

@J.N. First make sure it works when compiling directly in the terminal.

even got the MSYS2 build of gcc and I still get a similar message to my original problem, just with different paths. I also had a friend of mine download the MinGW compiler, same error for them too. Made sure to compile with the -lstdc++exp flag as well.

@HolyBlackCat I didn't read your first comment properly. Thank you so much. I've added the flag to the right of the file name and everything works.

Referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/78466486/13059668
If you want to use CmakeLists add the following line after add_executable
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "-lstdc++exp")


This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
